# ResearchKit error: 'Could not add Keychain item' for ORKPasscodeStep after converted to Swift 3

Tags: researchkit

Apple ResearchKit project: after updated to XCode 8 and converted to Swift 3, getting the error message 'Could not add Keychain item.' for ORKPasscodeStep. Is it a framework bug? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the `Keychain Sharing` capability for your app. See [here](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/826) for more info.